# split/regex apenas na primeira barra vertical "|"

Tags: javascript, regex

Quero dividir a *string* em 2 partes (sempre será uma *array* divida em duas partes - ou dois elementos) toda vez que uma barra vertical `|` (somente no primeiro caso).

Por exemplo: tenho uma string

`var string = "João|23anos";`

posso dar um `string.split("|")` e retorno será uma array `["João", "23 anos"]`. Porém, eu gostaria de dar split **apenas** no primeiro caso de barra vertical `|` e copiar o restante da *string* para a *array*;

Por exemplo:

`var string = "João|||23anos|";` <- Neste exemplo ele retornará essa array: `["João", "", "", "23anos", ""]`.

*Array* que eu desejaria ser impresso:

`["João", "||23anos|"]`

A primeira barra vertical só vai servir para dar `split` e o restante das barras verticais deverão estar dentro da array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Um maneira bem simples seria de obter o comprimento da primeira parte (`João`) e então usa-la para pegar todo o resto.

Por exemplo:

```js
texto = "João|||23anos|";
partes = [];

partes.push( texto.split('|')[0] );
partes.push( texto.substring(partes[0].length + 1) );

console.log(partes);
```

Acredito que o código esteja auto-explicativo. Primeiro ele obtêm a primeira parte (até o primeiro `|`), depois ele usa o comprimento do texto (neste caso 4) e soma com 1, então ele pega todo o texto a partir do quinto caractere.

*Como comentado pode utilizar somente `indexOf`, ignorando o `split`, como respondido pelo [@Anderson Carlos Woss](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/216339/15089)*

Comment: No JS num teria o equivalente ao `indexOf`? Isso seria mais direto ao assunto do que usar um split

Comment: vou te dar positivo por ser o primeiro a dar a resposta.

Answer (score 6):

```js
var str = 'João|||23anos|';
var splits = str.match(/([^|]*)\|(.*)/);
splits.shift();
console.log(splits);
```

Explicação:

- `str.match(/([^|]*)\|(.*)/);` retorna `2 Groups` mais o `Full Match`, então o Array irá conter o texto mais os 2 groups:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- Use [`shift()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_shift.asp) para remover o primeiro elemento do `Array` que é o `Full Match`.

Caso queria testar algum `Regex` recomendo usar essa ferramenta [`Regex101`](https://regex101.com/).

Comment: tem alguma dica para aprender ``regex``? desde as básicas até as avançadas

Comment: +1, mas é _full match_, com "TCH" ;-)

Comment: @Wtrmute Obrigado, tinha escrito errado!

Answer (score 6):

Utilizando `indexOf` para procurar a primeira ocorrência do caractere e dividir o texto, `slice`, nesta posição:

```js
const text = "João|||23anos|";

let firstMatch = text.indexOf('|');
let parts = [text.slice(0, firstMatch), text.slice(firstMatch+1)];

console.log(parts);
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var string = "João|||23anos|";

var ret = string.split(/\|(\|*\s*[\w.]+\s*\|*)/, 2);

console.log(ret);
```

Explicando:

No [regexp](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) a barra vertical(`|`) será nosso separador e entre parênteses o que queremos capturar.

O segundo argumento de [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) limita o número de divisões.

Answer (score 2):

Você também pode desejar fazer assim usando `.shift` para pegar o primeiro item e `.join` para "restaurar" o **resto** como string novamente:

```js
var str = "João|||23anos|";

//Divide a string
var results = str.split('|');

//Pega o primeiro resultado
var first = results.shift();

//Unifica os resultados restantes em uma nova string
var last = results.join('|');

//Cria um array baseado nos resultados
var result = [first, last];

console.log(result);
```

> **Nota:** o [`.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) tem um parâmetro chamado `limit`:
>
> ```
> str.split([separator[, limit]])
> ```
>
> No entanto o que ele faz é limitar os resultados

Answer (score 2):

Como se trata da primeira ocorrência, você poderia fazer assim :

```js
text = "João|||23anos|";
console.log(text.replace('|', '{spl}')); // SUBSTITUI A PRIMEIRA OCORRENCIA
console.log(text.replace('|', '{spl}').split('{spl}')); // DIVIDE PELO SEPARADOR
```

#### Explicação

- `.replace('|', '{spl}')` - o `replace` vai substituir o primeira ocorrência pelo nosso separador `{spl}`
- `.split('{spl}')` - O `split` vai dividir a sentença pelo nosso separador.

#### Nota

- `{spl}` - é meramente ilustrativo, poderia ser um simples `$` ou `@`.

Answer (score 2):

```js
texto = "João|||23anos|";
console.log(texto.split(/\|(.*)/,2));
```

Answer (score 0):

### Usando [`slice`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_string.asp) e [`split`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp)

```js
var texto = "João|||23anos|";
var resultado = texto.split("|", 1).concat([texto.slice(texto.indexOf("|") + 1)]);

console.log(resultado);
```